# ffill not filling data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe like this :

```
  A  B  C  E D
---------------
0 a  r  g    g
1            x
2 x  f  f    r
3            t
3            y
```

I am trying for forward filling using ffill. It is not working

```
 cols = df.columns[:4].tolist()
 df[cols] = df[cols].ffill()
```

I also tried :

```
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(method='ffill')
```

But it is not getting filled. 
Is it the empty columns in data causing this issue?

Data is mocked. Exact data is different (contains strings,numbers and empty columns)

desired o/p:

```
  A  B  C  E D
---------------
0 a  r  g    g
1 a  r  g    x
2 x  f  f    r
3 x  f  f    t
3 x  f  f    y
```

Comment: Whats the desired output?

Comment: What are the empty values in the data frame, empty strings? or?

Comment: empty strings...

Answer (score 2):

Replace empty values in subset of columns by `NaN`:

```
df[cols] = df[cols].replace('', np.nan).ffill()
```

Comment: Maybe some whitespaces instead empty sttrings? `df[cols] = df[cols].replace('\s+', np.nan).ffill()` working?

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the empty strings with `np.NaN` before:

```
df = df.replace('', np.NaN)
df[cols] = df[cols].ffill()
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `''` with `np.nan` first:

```
df[df='']=np.nan
df[cols] = df[cols].ffill()
```